# Performance comparison of two ML models

Tags: classification, cross-validation, model-evaluation

I have a dataset $X$, containing data and binary labels, which I want to use to create a binary classifier.

Suppose I've made two different models, $A$ and $B$, both binary classifiers, and want to compare their performance. When creating either $A$ or $B$, I split $X$ into three parts ($X_1$ for training, $X_2$ for crossvalidation and model optimization, and $X_3$ for benchmarking).

Let's say that $A$ and $B$ both perform comparably well, but not exactly the same (i.e, $A$ performs *slightly* better than $B$ on $X_3$).

1. Can I conclude that $A$ is better than $B$, to the best of my
   knowledge/effort?
2. If not, what can I do to conclusively show which method is better,
   or if there is in fact a tie?